# Bootstrap broker not being used to consume from topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

A simple spring-boot-kafka which consumes from a topic on a network cluster:

Errors:

> Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

> Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be
> established. Broker may not be available.

Puzzle:

> The configured broker is **not** local, it's *BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094*, and it
> is available.

pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

config class:

```
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@PropertySource("dv/application.properties")
public class KafkaConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_1");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Consumer Class:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "foo_topic", groupId = "group_1")
    public void consume(String message) {
        log.info(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the *ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG* setting, the correct boostrap server wasn't being used. The ConsumerConfig values in the log was: *bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]*.

I needed to change the Bean name from "concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory" to "kafkaListenerContainerFactory". So:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
```

needed to change to:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
```

Once I made this single change, the bootstrap server were correctly recognized for the configured listener.

Now, the ConsumerConfig log shows:

> *bootstrap.servers=[BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094]*

Moreover, the bootstrap server doesn't need to configure advertised.listeners, despite the implication of this article: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/.

When I asked our Kafka admin about adding advertised.listeners, he told me that he had actually removed them for simplicity and sent me this configuration description:

> **advertised.listeners**
>
> use, *if different than* the listeners config property. In IaaS
> environments, this may need to be different from the interface to
> which the broker binds. If this is not set, the value for listeners
> will be used. Unlike listeners, it is not valid to advertise the
> 0.0.0.0 meta-address. Also unlike listeners, there can be duplicated ports in this property, so that one listener can be configured to
> advertise another listener's address. This can be useful in some cases
> where external load balancers are used.Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to

He is correct because I am getting the correct the expected meta-data when using kafkacat:

```
kafkacat -b BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094 -L
```

which returns :

```
Metadata for all topics (from broker 2: sasl_ssl://xx.foo.net:9094/2):   
5 brokers:   
broker 5 at xx22.ttgtpmg.net:9094 (controller)    
broker 4 at xx21.ttgtpmg.net:9094   
broker 1 at xx18.ttgtpmg.net:9094   
broker 2 at xx19.ttgtpmg.net:9094   
broker 3 at xx20.ttgtpmg.net:9094
```

Comment: Overall, I'd suggest adding `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` and other configs in your properties file. That way, you don't need to workaround bean names

Comment: Thanks, yes... that is the plan. This same instance will eventually run in many different k8s (and kafka) environments; the properties files will exist in the k8s configmaps.

Comment: Can anyone explain (or have a source) why the name of the bean matters?

Answer (score 3):

> it's BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094, and it is available.

The bootstrap port may be available and responding to requests, but that broker then ***returned***   it's configured `advertised.listeners`.

Based on your error, either

1. that's set to be localhost/127.0.0.1:9092
2. **or** you're getting the default Spring property for the bootstrap servers config

Comment: > kafkacat -b BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094 -L

I see 4 brokers and (one is the controller) and they're all fully qualified names! No "localhost".

 4 brokers:
  broker 5 at BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094 (controller)
  broker 4 at BROKER_2.FOO.NET:9094
  broker 2 at BROKER_3.FOO.NET:9094
  broker 3 at BROKER_4.FOO.NET:9094

Looking at the server.properties on the bootstrap broker, I don't see any advertised.listeners property configured. Yet, the kafkacat results don't seem to make sense.

Comment: If the property is not defined in the properties, then it defaults to the machine's local hostname rather than any external DNS name

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain the kafkacat output.

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense? Those are the listed listener addresses. Note: if `kafkacat -C -b BROKER_1.FOO.NET:9094` works from the same machine as the Java code, then something is misconfigured in the Java code

Comment: In https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/, the author demonstrates that kafkacat used with -L will return the metadata as seen by the client. In his example it returns localhost/127.0.0.1:9092. Yet in my case it returns fully qualified host addresses.

Comment: It also returns `broker 0 at ip-172-31-18-160.us-west-2.compute.internal:9092` in AWS and `kafka0:29092` in Docker, so I dont understand what you're asking

Comment: The brokers are remote, same network as me via a VPN. The java app receives meta-data from the bootstrap that says "localhost/127.0.0.1:9092". Then I run kafkacat -L against the same bootstrap from the same computer as the java app, and it returns different meta-data than the app. This article explains that kafkacat -L will show you the same meta-data seen from a consumer/producer, yet it doesn't. Why not?

Comment: I've honestly never ran it from a VPN, but it should work the same since, like I said, I think you've got a Java misconfiguration because Spring defines a default for `bootstrap.servers` set to localhost. So, since you're not actually using or have shown your `application.properties` file, I suggest creating a [mcve] using `kafka-clients` alone without spring.

Comment: There actually were no application.properties pertaining to kafka. This problem as described below can be reproduced with the given code.

Comment: So, my suspicion was correct that it was a Java code misconfiguration. Glad you figured it out